# Angular2 jasmine unit test component with third party directive

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Component is https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap  dropdown.

in template i have this:

```
    <span dropdown placement="bottom right">
      <a id="droplist-label" href="javascript:void(0)" dropdownToggle>
          <span>{{conf.title}}</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" *dropdownMenu>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items">
          <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="listClick(item.value)" href="javascript:void(0)">{{item.label}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </span>
```

The ul is not added until the label is clicked - therefor i cannot access it in the test.

Calling click:

```
let droplist = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#droplist-label')).nativeElement;
droplist.click();
```

Does not work - if i try to look for `dropdown-menu` it is empty:

```
it('should test if droplist has title',  async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let droplist = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#droplist-label')).nativeElement;
    droplist.click();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        let droplistOptions = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.dropdown-item'));
        expect(droplistOptions.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
}));
```

The directive has a hostlistener for click event it seems - how can i trigger it so the ul becomes available?

Comment: Seems like if the component uses <template> inside  - queryAll does not work properly if you look by anything that goes inside the <template>. Had to use .children to get the list of elements.

Comment: Same problem for me...

Comment: @M'sieurToph' look at my answer.

Comment: Thx ... look at mine too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution i came up with to the problem above - using children to get the elements inside.

```
it('should test if droplist has listed correct values',  async(() => {
    comp.isOpen = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        let droplist = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.dropdown-menu'));
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(droplist.children.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        let i = 0;
        for(let item of droplist.children) {
            let anchorElement = item.children[0].nativeElement;
            expect(anchorElement.innerText).toBe(droplistItems[i].label);
            expect(anchorElement.getAttribute('data-value')).toBe(droplistItems[i].value);
            i++;
        }
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 5):

I finally solved the same pb using [fakeAsync()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#fake-async) :

```
it('should render submenus', fakeAsync(() => {

  fixture.detectChanges(); // update the view

  // trig submenus opening
  let toggleButtons = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('[dropdownToggle]');
  toggleButtons.forEach(b => b.click());


  tick();                  // wait for async tasks to end
  fixture.detectChanges(); // update the view

  // then count how many items you got for each submenus.
  let droplistOptions1= fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('#first-ul > li')
  let droplistOptions2= fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('#second-ul > li')
  let droplistOptions3= fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('#third-ul > li')
  expect(droplistOptions1.length).toEqual(3);
  expect(droplistOptions2.length).toEqual(5);
  expect(droplistOptions3.length).toEqual(2);
}));
```

But I am sure it is possible to do it with an `async()` : I guess you only missed a `fixture.detectChanges()` at the beginning of the `fixture.whenStable().then(...)` in your initial try.

---

Also, remember to import the BsDropdownModule into your testbed :

```
import { BsDropdownModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  ...
});
```